# How to undo the perspective distortion caused by projections?

Tags: texturing, shaders, camera, shader-nodes, project

When projecting a texture with the UV Project modifier or by using the texture coordinates of an object there is a distortion caused by the perspective. This is what I'm referring too:
[image: 1]

As you can see in this example, parts of the shape of the Suzanne head are still visible during the projection. This creates cuts in the quadratic sphere texture. These cuts I would like to get rid of somehow.

Both objects used for these projections are aimed at the camera. Both Material Output nodes give the same visual result. The file can be downloaded below.

I was able to find [this question that tackles a very similar problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290281/forces-perspective-distorted-image-using-uvproject-modifier), the reason that this solution doesn't work for me is that the projection is happening through the camera object, while I'd like to be able to manipulate the location, rotation and scaling of these projections through an empty object. Imagine this effect being used to project a texture onto a specific part of a character's body as it moves around.

So is there a way to create object based projections while preventing or undoing the aforementioned distortion?

[image]

Comment: I think you can use X/Z only in the object texture coordinate, with some scale.

Comment: To achieve the match (absence of cuts)  in the view, the view perspective, (wherever the view is from),  has to be the same as the projector perspective. The match is view-dependent. However you transform the projection, it would have to be driven by your _current_ view, to match in that view. When do you want the match to occur, if not looking through the viewing camera?

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you for your comment! It's not a problem if it only works while using the viewing camera.

Comment: @lemon Yeah the scaling is the issue, I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: But as said @RobinBetts, the effect won't be clean except if aligned to the cam https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NYbz.gif ... do you want that ?

Comment: @BrockoliBruce, can we ask why not use the viewing camera to project? It would be the easiest way.. otherwise we have to figure out how to match FOV / focal length

Comment: @lemon Yes, if it only works through the camera view that's not an issue. Other effects I've made also only work when aligned to the camera view.

Comment: But if only from the cam view, why do you want to use another object for the projection?

Comment: @RobinBetts Like in the other post I linked to? It would be the easiest way, but in my case I'd like to use this in conjunction with character animation. Imagine a texture being projected onto a specific part of a character's body.
Matching the FOV/focal length does sound tricky... Could Geometry Nodes help with any of this?
Thanks for the quick replies btw, appreciated.

Comment: @lemon Ahh I see, it's because I'd like to use this for character animation. Pleases ee my reply to RobinBetts. I'll clarify this in the question as it seems to cause some confusion.